# Building a User Script for Chrome using ClojureScript, how can I get the UserScript comment block to exist in compiled output?

Tags: comments, userscripts, clojurescript

I'm trying to create a UserScript in Chrome using ClojureScript.  The issue I am having is that the `<name>.user.js` file needs a comment block at the top that declares attributes about the UserScript.

It looks something like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name CLJS Hello World
// @namespace http://something.com/my_cljs_user_script
// @author spoon16
// @include *
// ==/UserScript==
```

How can I include this block in the compiled JS file?

Answer (score 1):

(ongoing discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/clojurescript/_qViDrdu30U))

1. add a foreign-libs marker to your cljsbuild build spec (in case you are using cljsbuild), here's what I added:

   ```
   :foreign-libs [{:file "comment-block.js" :provides ["comment.block"]}]
   ```
2. add that foreign "lib". Here's what mine contains:

   ```
   /**
    * @fileoverview
    * This file contains nothing but a comment block which is to be preserved 
    * by the google closure compiler. This comment block contains a comment
    * block which is necessary to be in the output of the compiled javascript
    * even in advanced compilation mode.
    */
   /**
    * @preserve
   // ==UserScript==
   // @description Description of the user script
   // @include INCLUDESPEC HERE
   // @include ETC ETC
   // @name user script name
   // ==/UserScript==
   */
   ```
3. (require) your foreign lib.

   ```
   (require [comment.block :as ignored])
   ```
4. run your (advanced) compilation. Somewhere in the compiled output, the UserScript block will appear (note that the user script block requires to be at column 0, beginning with // style comments, which is why there's that newline after `@preserve`).
5. call the compiled output something akin `blablabla.user.js` (suffix `'user.js'` is required), greasemonkey will recognize it, pick up the data from the user script block, and there's unicorns for everybody (even the vegans!)

Answer (score 0):

I think your best best would be to use two separate files -- one being the UserScript template that remains as a javascript file and the other the actual ClojureScript which gets compiled.  Just include the function that executes the desired ClojureScript.